# MvvmCross fragments resolving

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm using Xamarin with MvvmCross, and have problem with fragments usage.

I call ShowViewModel so:

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public override void Start()
    {
        ShowViewModel<MainMenuViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Where MainMenuViewModel it's class:

```
public class MainMenuViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
}
```

Implemented fragment as follows:

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(MainMenuViewModel), Resource.Id.navigation_frame)]
[Register("mvvm.droid.views.MainMenuView")]
public class MainMenuView : MvxFragment<MainMenuViewModel>
{
   public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
      return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.MainMenuView, null);
   }
}
```

But on runtime it throws error:

> Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {Mvvm.Droid/md5f67dcc55ddb5809d2766dd0c42c8b3bb.MainMenuView};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

For figuring out this, i implemented CustomPresenter, taken from [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Droid/Shared/Presenter/MvxFragmentsPresenter.cs).

And in Setup registered this presenter for fragments:

```
protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
{
   var mvxFragmentsPresenter = new MvxCustomFragmentsPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
   Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAndroidViewPresenter>(mvxFragmentsPresenter);
   return mvxFragmentsPresenter;
}
```

It seems like presenter found fragments, but at Show(Intent) method call it's still crushing. In decompiled sources there is a strange check if it's an activity.
Tryed to implement drawerLayout based on many implementations, but the same result. What i'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in your `MvxFragment` attribute:

> [MvxFragment(typeof(**MainMenuViewModel**), Resource.Id.navigation_frame)]

The first parameter needs to be the `MvxViewModel` associated to your Activity that you want to place the menu fragment in. In your case I believe this may be `MainViewModel`?

Mvvmcross [description](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/8a824c797747f74716fc64c2fd0e8765c29b16ab/MvvmCross/Droid/Shared/Attributes/MvxFragmentAttribute.cs#L15) of MvxFragment attribute:

```
public MvxFragmentAttribute(
    Type parentActivityViewModelType, 
    int fragmentContentId, 
    bool addToBackStack = false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent hours on figuring out the problem.