# Init method is not called in Fragment view model

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a fragment where in the init method I'm trying to show some data, But it is not getting.

```
namespace MoneyCare.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        public FirstViewModel First {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public SecondViewModel Second {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public ThirdViewModel Third {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            First = new FirstViewModel();
            Second = new SecondViewModel();
            Third = new ThirdViewModel();
        }
    }

}
```

I have three fragments in my project.

```
namespace MoneyCare.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class FirstViewModel: MvxViewModel
    {
        Friend _friend;
        public List<Friend> AllFriends {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string FriendUserName
        {
            get {
                return _friend.FriendUserName;
            }
            set
            {
                _friend.FriendUserName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => FriendUserName);
            }
        }
        public void Init()
        {
            Task<List<Friend>> result = Mvx.Resolve<Repository>().getFriendsList();
            result.Wait();
            AllFriends = result.Result;
        }
        public ICommand check
        {
            get
            {
                return new MvxCommand(() =>
                {
                    //Task<List<Friend>> result = Mvx.Resolve<Repository>().getFriendsList();
                    //result.Wait();
                    //AllFriends = result.Result;
                    ShowViewModel<CheckViewModel>();
                });
            }
        }
        //Opens Add Friends Activity
        public ICommand OpenAddFriend
        {
            get
            {
                return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<AddFriendViewModel>());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I tried the same thing with Activity, For `checkview` activity, it is working but not for Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ViewModel`'s lifecycles are not being executed because you're not *loading* them with MvvmCross, you're just constructing them as you would ordinary .NET classes. Only the constructor will actually run. If you want `Init` to execute, you need to load the ViewModel with MvvmCross, which is typically done by navigating to it with `ShowViewModel<YourViewModel>`.

Fragments being contained by activities in Android doesn't mean that your ViewModels need to be children of your `HomeViewModel`. Calling `ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel>` will ensure that `FirstViewModel`'s `Init`fires.

Comment: How can I call ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel> from HomeViewModel ?In a Init method of HomeViewModel  ?

Comment: No - you shouldn't navigate away from a ViewModel during `Init`. If `HomeViewModel` is the ViewModel for the activity that contains the fragment that `FirstViewModel` is linked to, navigate to `FirstViewModel` _instead of_ `HomeViewModel`. Ensure that Android loads the activity for the fragment by using the `MvxFragment` attribute like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287483/mvvmcross-fragments-resolving) example.